# Integral ${\large\int}_0^\infty\frac{\ln x}{1+x}\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}}\ \mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, closed-form

Please help me to evaluate this integral:
$$
I={\large\int}_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\left(x\right) \over 1 + x}\,
\,\sqrt{\,x + \sqrt{\,1 + x^{2}\,}\, \over 1 + x^{2}\,}\,\,{\rm d}x.\tag1
$$
*Mathematica* could not evaluate it in a closed form. A numerical integration returned
$$I \approx 4.25314982536869548103063\ldots\,,\tag2$$
but neither
[*WolframAlpha*](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=4.25314982536869548103063) nor [*ISC+*](http://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/standardCalc?input=4.25314982536869548103063) could find a plausible closed form for this.

Comment: Maybe it just doesn't exist?

Comment: It can be rewritten as $\quad\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{\ln(\sinh x)}{1+\sinh x}\cdot e^{x/2}~dx,\quad$ for which Mathematica is able to return a hideous expression.

Comment: @Lucian I simplified the result to 3 lines with only 1 `PolyLog` term, but it still looks bad...

Comment: Is there anymore background information on the integral. Eg. From a problem? If you created it yourself, try and play around with the bounds and see if there are nicer expressions.

Comment: @Lucian Your observation already suffices to obtain an answer. After the substitution $t=e^{x/2}$ the integral becomes $\int R(t)\ln t\,dt$ with rational $R(t)$, and thus can always be computed in terms of dilogarithms.

Comment: I think you may use residues (Contour integration) before that use O. L.  Hint

Comment: I summon you @Cleo

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With some help from a CAS I got this result with only one dilogarithm term:
$$I=\frac{\sqrt[4]2\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}{16}\\\left\{\left[16\ln2+\left(1+\sqrt2\right)\left(4\pi-16\arctan\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}\right)\right]\ln\left(1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}\right)\\-\Big(32\left(1+\sqrt2\right)\ln2+4\pi\Big)\arctan\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}-3\pi\arctan\frac{2\sqrt{2+10\sqrt2}}7\\-16\arctan^2\sqrt{\sqrt2-1}+4\ln^2\!\left(1+\sqrt2+\sqrt{2+2\sqrt2}\right)\\+3\pi^2-\frac{32}{\sqrt{2-\sqrt2}}\,\Re\left[\left(-1\right)^{5/8}\operatorname{Li}_2\!\left(2i\left( 1+\sqrt{1+i}\right)\right)\right]\right\}.$$

---

*Update:* It was suggested in comments that this expression gives a numerically incorrect result when evaluated with *Maple*. Here is what I got with *Maple 18*:

[image: Maple screenshot]

This value numerically matches the integral. I also checked it with *Mathematica 10* and it gave the same numeric result.

Comment: How did you do this?

Comment: I started with a large expression similar to one given in another answer, then simplified it using _Mathematica_, then using _Maple_, then manually, and again, and again..., and finally I got this :) I do not recall any particularly remarkable idea that I used during this process.

Comment: Compared with the other answer, this is positively elegant.

Comment: Forgive my obscure reference to [Spartacus](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1442449), but: *The bringer of results!... The slayer of integrals!... The champion of Stack Exchange!... VLADIMIR !!!* :-)

Comment: It looks like Cleo's style answer

Comment: @V-Moy Cleo's answers usually cannot be easily obtained using _Mathematica_ or _Maple_. Clearly, she communicates directly with Namagiri :)

Comment: Anyway, could you please look for closed-forms of my problem using Mathematica or Maple: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/917154/133248 Thanks. (✿◠‿◠)

Answer (score 22):

\begin{align}
-\frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x}\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}}{\rm d}x
&=-\frac{1}{4}\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln{\sinh{x}}}{1+\sinh{x}}e^{x/2}{\rm d}x\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\int^\infty_1\frac{\ln\left(\frac{x^2-x^{-2}}{2}\right)}{1+\frac{x^2-x^{-2}}{2}}{\rm d}x\\
&=\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-x^4)-\ln(2x^2)}{x^4-2x^2-1}{\rm d}x\\
\end{align}
For simplicity's sake, let $\displaystyle\frac{1}{x^4-2x^2-1}=\sum^4_{k=1}\frac{c_k}{x-r_k}$. The integral becomes
$$I=-4\sum^4_{k=1}\int^1_0\frac{c_k\ln(1-x^4)-c_k\ln{2}-2c_k\ln{x}}{x-r_k}{\rm d}x$$
The second integral is
\begin{align}
-c_k\ln{2}\int^1_0\frac{1}{x-r_k}{\rm d}x=-c_k\ln{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-r_k}{-r_k}\right)
\end{align}
The third integral is
\begin{align}
-2c_k\int^1_0\frac{\ln{x}}{x-r_k}{\rm d}x
&=2c_k\int^{1/r_k}_0\frac{\ln(r_kx)}{1-x}{\rm d}x\\
&=-2c_k{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{r_k}\right)
\end{align}
Pluck these results back in.
$$I=4\sum^4_{k=1}c_k\left[\ln{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-r_k}{-r_k}\right)+2{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{r_k}\right)-\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-x^4)}{x-r_k}{\rm d}x\right]$$
The remaining integral is
\begin{align}
&\ \ \ \ \ \int^1_0\frac{\ln(1-x^4)}{x-r_k}{\rm d}x\\
&=\sum_{j=1,-1,i,-i}\int^1_0\frac{\ln(1+jx)}{x-r_k}{\rm d}x\\
&=-\sum_{j=1,-1,i,-i}\int^{\frac{\lambda}{1-r_k}}_{-\frac{\lambda}{r_k}}\ln\left(1+\frac{j\lambda}{y}+jr_k\right)\frac{{\rm d}y}{y}\\
&=-\sum_{j=1,-1,i,-i}\int^{\frac{\lambda}{1-r_k}}_{-\frac{\lambda}{r_k}}\left[\ln\left(1+\frac{1+jr_k}{j\lambda}y\right)-\ln\left(\frac{y}{j\lambda}\right)\right]\frac{{\rm d}y}{y}\\
&=-\sum_{j=1,-1,i,-i}\int^{\frac{1+jr_k}{j-jr_k}}_{-\frac{1+jr_k}{jr_k}}\frac{\ln(1+y)}{y}-\frac{1}{y}\ln\left(\frac{y}{1+jr_k}\right){\rm d}y\\
&=-\sum_{j=1,-1,i,-i}\left[{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1+jr_k}{jr_k}\right)-{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1+jr_k}{jr_k-j}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2\left(-jr_k\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2\left(j-jr_k\right)\right]
\end{align}
**Final Result:**
\begin{align}
\color\purple{\int^\infty_0\frac{\ln{x}}{1+x}\sqrt{\frac{x+\sqrt{1+x^2}}{1+x^2}}{\rm d}x
=4\sum^4_{k=1}c_k\left[\ln{2}\ln\left(\frac{1-r_k}{-r_k}\right)+2{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{r_k}\right)+\sum_{j=1,-1,i,-i}\left[{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1+jr_k}{jr_k}\right)-{\rm Li}_2\left(\frac{1+jr_k}{jr_k-j}\right)+\frac{1}{2}\ln^2\left(-jr_k\right)-\frac{1}{2}\ln^2\left(j-jr_k\right)\right]\right]}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\frac{c_1}{x-r_1}&=\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}\left(x-\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
\frac{c_2}{x-r_2}&=-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2+2\sqrt{2}}\left(x+\sqrt{1+\sqrt{2}}\right)}\\
\frac{c_3}{x-r_3}&=-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}\left(x+i\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}\right)}\\
\frac{c_4}{x-r_4}&=-\frac{1}{4\sqrt{2}\left(x-i\sqrt{\sqrt{2}-1}\right)}\\
\end{align}

Comment: Do you think these sums can be evaluated? Probably not, but would like your comments @SuperAbound

Comment: @AlexanderGiles Technically, they can be, but it is certainly not possible by hand, as would get an ugly barrage of terms as shown in user153012's answer.

Comment: OK nice. Interesting work.

Comment: Great job! Makes much more sense than the crazy Maple output.

Comment: @Winther Thank you for your compliment. I appreciate it.

Comment: The numerical value doesn't match the other answer. At least the $2$ in $2\log2\log(\cdots)$ looks wrong.

Comment: @Kirill Do you mind enlightening me on what you mean by "looks wrong"? Please correct me if I am wrong, but the term you mentioned came from splitting up the term $\ln(2x^2)=\ln{2}+2\ln{x}$, and that seems to be a legitimate step. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @SuperAbound The answer's numerical value doesn't match the integral's numerical value, that's the main issue. What I meant was: you have $-4\sum_k\int\frac{-c_k \log 2}{x-r_k}$ in one line, evaluate the integral to $-c_k\log2\log\frac{1-r_k}{-r_k}$, and then in the answer you have $4\sum_k c_k(2\log2\log\frac{1-r_k}{-r_k})$, where the $2$ came out of nowhere. I also think the evaluation of $\int\frac{\log(1-x^4)}{x-r_k}$ is incorrect, it doesn't match the integral numerically, according to my computer.

Comment: @Kirill I certainly see what you mean by "appear out of nowhere now. It was really careless of me to have made that mistake. I have fixed it and thank you for pointing that out and putting up with my ignorance. As for the evaluation for the last integral, it seems to match the identity in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/892805/integral-involving-dilogarithms). However, I will double-check my working again to find any errors.

Comment: @SuperAbound I haven't checked your solution myself, but the issue might be that $\log(ab)=\log a+\log b$ isn't necessary true for arbitrary $a$ and $b$ in the complex plane, depending on their phase and the logarithm's branch cut. [For reference here is the relevant formula](http://functions.wolfram.com/ElementaryFunctions/Log/21/01/02/0003/).

Answer (score 15):

Okay, first of all: it is not easy to answer this question, and I'm not able to show the truth in an elegant way. I did the job with [*Maple*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maple_(software)) [computer algebra system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_algebra_system) (CAS).

In this form there is no chance to evaulate to solution even with CAS, so we transform into the form, what @Lucian offered. Let $f$ be
$$f:=\frac{\ln(\sinh x)}{1+ \sinh x} \cdot e^{x/2}$$

I calculated for you the indefinite integral $\int f(x) \ dx$. It is too long to render with $\LaTeX$, so I paste here the raw Maple output:

[image: indefinite integral]

After that I calculated the definite integral $\int_0^{\infty} f(x) \ dx$. Here is the closed form:

[image: definite integral]

Which is by 100 digits precision: $4.253149825368695481030630266176679795147658282 \\ 387249226057297960587772473334190569825379100016048097$

A good approximation for this integral for example
$$\frac{5}{9} \cdot 3^{4/5} \cdot 5^{2/3} \cdot \ln(3)^{8/9}.$$
The value of this one is $4.2531498232523271$ which is correct for $9$ digits, and also has quite an easy form.

If you need the closed form in raw text I can paste here. For a more accurate answer I think we need here @Cleo or @Tunk-Fey.

Comment: After about 4 days I tried to crack this integral, I decided to gave up. Of course I have a partial answer, but as a partial answer it turns out somewhat too lengthy and messy. I doubt it can be solved analytically. Maybe @Cleo can do it.